# Visual Studio syntax highlighting rules: knowing which one was applied

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

In visual studio, is there any way to tell by which rule or category a specific word/symbol was highlighted? In VS2012 there are so many categories that it's harder to determine which one applies for the element you'd like to modify (for example: C++ user types, C++ user types (generic type), C++ user types (reference type), etc)